# Django template how to remove repeated values?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Is there a way to say to Django to hide/remove (show a blank space) for fields that got same values as previous row?

i.e.: if now is equal for differents Articles can it be show only for the first of the group?

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.utils import timezone

from articles.models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):

    model = Article

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context


<h1>Articles</h1>
<ul>
{% for article in object_list %}
    <li>{{ article.pub_date|date }} - {{ article.headline }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No articles yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

> Article  -   now
>
> a          - 2017-01-01
>
> b          -
>
> c          - 2017-01-02
>
> d          -

Is this possible from **view** or directly in **template**?

Comment: I'm not sure what that yellow block is supposed to show, but you almost certainly want [`{% ifchanged %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ifchanged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) which:

> Checks if a value has changed from the last iteration of a loop.

as follows:

```
<h1>Articles</h1>
<ul>
{% for article in object_list %}
    <li>{{ article.headline }} - {% ifchanged article.pub_date|date %} 
        {{ article.pub_date|date }} {% endifchanged %}
   </li>
{% empty %}
    <li>No articles yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will check in each iteration the value of `article.pub_date` and **only when** that value changes it will be displayed.

Good luck :)